# Is horizontal scrolling possible in android?

Tags: android

I want to get same effect of home screen in samsung android phone, i.e., we have to drag screen horizontally to view all applications and we will get screen numbers on top side as 1, 2, 3, ... Is it possible to create an app like that?? If anyone know this reply me.

Thanks,
Yugandhar

Answer (score 4):

Use the [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) detailed there and this can be combined with the [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) to provide the nice title effect.